# What does the ^ do?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm new to C++ programming and am going through some examples that I found a while back. Since I am a decent Java programmer, I'm making good progress (at least from my perspective :D).

Now I've come across something I cannot figure out what it does:

```
Threading::Thread ^ th = Threading::Thread::CurrentThread;
Net::IPEndPoint^ hostEp;
```

What is the purpose of the `^`? And is there a difference between the useage in the two lines I've only known this to be the XOR Operator.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not C++, that's for sure...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code is not C++, it is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI). `^` is an extension that denotes a pointer to a managed object instance.